Pycharm unused import statment pandas
I am new on python and I am trying to get data from a website with BeatifulSoup and here is my code
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pandas

current_page = 1

proceed = True

while proceed:
    url = "https://#"

    page = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

    if soup.title.text == "404 Not Found":
        proceed = False
    else:
        all_product = soup.find_all("img", class_="alt")

        for product in all_product:
            item = dict()

            item['Title'] = product.find("img").attrs["alt"]
            item['Title'] = product.find("a").attrs["href"]
            item['Price'] = product.find("strong", class_="price")

            print(item['Price'])

    current_page += 1
    proceed = False

I installed all requirements, when I checked from settings pycharm on project python interpreter there are all require library and its still giving:
Unused import  statement 'import pandas as pd' Error


What's the problem? I see import pandas as pandas and that's not used in this code. Have you tried removing that line?

See also similar question about PyCharms code-inspection and how to fix it with action Optimize Imports - JetBrains Guide.

Does this answer your question? Unused Import Statement - Warning message
